# Regarding strongly typed dataset in windows form application

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, .net-3.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace GST.Masters
{
public partial class Customers : Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Forms.MainUC
{
public static string recCode
{ get; set; }
public string RC;
public bool insertFlag;
public Data.GSTDb.CustomersRow r;
public Data.GSTDb.CustomersGSTNosRow gr;
public Data.GSTDb.CustomersDataTable dt = new Data.GSTDb.CustomersDataTable();
public Customers()
{
InitializeComponent();
recCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Customers_Load);
this.Ts.SaveClicked += new Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Menu.ToolStrip.SaveClickedEventHandler(this.Ts_SaveClicked);
this.Ts.AddNewClicked += new Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Menu.ToolStrip.AddNewClickedEventHandler(this.Ts_AddNewClicked);
this.Ts.SearchClicked += new Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Menu.ToolStrip.SearchClickedEventHandler(this.Ts_SearchClicked);
this.DgGST.CellValidated += (sender, e) =>
{
string name = this.DgGST.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
if (name == "DGCCountryCode")
{
name = this.DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[name].Value.ToString();
this.statesBindingSource.Filter = "ParentCode = '" + name + "'";
if (!this.FormIsLoading)
{
this.DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DGCStateCode"].Value = null;
this.DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DGCCityCode"].Value = null;
}
}
else if (name == "DGCStateCode")
{
name = this.DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[name].Value.ToString();
this.citiesBindingSource.Filter = "ParentCode = '" + name + "'";
if (!this.FormIsLoading)
{
this.DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DGCCityCode"].Value = null;
}
}
};
}
private void Ts_AddNewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.gSTDb.Customers.Rows.Clear();
r = this.gSTDb.Customers.NewCustomersRow();
this.gSTDb.Customers.AddCustomersRow(r);
Data.GSTDbTableAdapters.CustomersGSTNosTableAdapter CGT = new Data.GSTDbTableAdapters.CustomersGSTNosTableAdapter();
CGT.FillByParentCode(gSTDb.CustomersGSTNos, r.RecCode);
}
private void Ts_SearchClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Forms.SearchForm sf = new Heptanesia.Winforms.Ui.Forms.SearchForm();
sf.DataSource = new Data.GSTDbTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter().GetData();
sf.DisplayColumns = new string[] { "Name" };
sf.DisplayHeaders = new string[] { "Customers Name" };
sf.DisplayWidths = new int[] { 200 };
if (sf.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
this.RC = sf.ReturnRow["RecCode"].ToString();
this.customersTableAdapter.FillByRecCode(this.gSTDb.Customers, RC);
}
}
private void Ts_SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string message = "Error: ";
try
{
this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
//if (this.DgGST.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null)
this.fkCustomerGSTNosCustomersBindingSource.EndEdit();
if (this.gSTDb.Customers.HasErrors)
message += Classes.Global.SetBindingSourcePositionAndGetError(this.customersBindingSource, this.gSTDb.Customers.GetErrors()[0]);
else if (this.gSTDb.CustomersGSTNos.HasErrors)
message += Classes.Global.SetBindingSourcePositionAndGetError(this.fkCustomerGSTNosCustomersBindingSource, this.gSTDb.CustomersGSTNos.GetErrors()[0]);
else
{
this.gSTDb.Customers.BeforeSave();
this.gSTDb.CustomersGSTNos.BeforeSave();
Data.GSTDbTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager tm = new Data.GSTDbTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
tm.CustomersTableAdapter = this.customersTableAdapter;
tm.CustomersGSTNosTableAdapter = this.customersGSTNosTableAdapter;
tm.UpdateAll(this.gSTDb);
message = "Record(s) Saved Successfully";
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
message += ex.Message;
}
MessageBox.Show(message, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
private void Customers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.FormIsLoading = true;
this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.gSTDb.Customers);
this.customersGSTNosTableAdapter.Fill(this.gSTDb.CustomersGSTNos);
this.countriesTableAdapter.Fill(this.gSTDb.Countries);
this.statesTableAdapter.Fill(this.gSTDb.States);
this.citiesTableAdapter.Fill(this.gSTDb.Cities);
this.gSTDb.Customers.Rows.Clear();
if (this.gSTDb.Customers.Rows.Count == 0)
{
Data.GSTDb.CustomersRow r = this.gSTDb.Customers.NewCustomersRow();
this.gSTDb.Customers.AddCustomersRow(r);
}
this.FormIsLoading = false;
}
private void DgGST_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Exception is ArgumentException)
{
object value = DgGST.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
if (!((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)DgGST.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Contains(value))
{
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DgGST[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]).Value = DBNull.Value;
//((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Add(value);
e.ThrowException = false;
}
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
e.Cancel = true;
}
}
}
}
```

I am developing one simple invoice application in which I am having a simple Customer screen module.A Customer can have any number of GST records in the Datagridview.The Screen is based on Customer Masters(Textboxes) and Customers Master Details(Datagridview) relationship through foreign keys. And I am Using Strongly Typed Dataset in this project as a xsd file.This Screen has 3 buttons i.e.New,Save and Find toolstrip menu.

When I start adding records after clicking on New Buttonstrip and and save ,it saves it successfully and when I press New Ideally it should clear the rows.The main issue here is that it is not clearing the rows??

I am enclosing the cs file here.

What I have tried:

Everything as I can Do.

1. Clearing the Rows through Rows.Clear(); 2) I tried clearing
2. Binding Source and DataGridview after setting it null.

Nothing Worked.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: GSTDb.Customers.NewRow(); ? (instead of Rows.Clear)

Comment: There are two know issues with DGV : If you don't clear the DataTable DataSource the adapter will append the data to the existing table 2) The DGV doesn't automatically get updated.  The Paint Event doesn't get called.  So the trick is to set the datasource to null and then back to the datatable so the DGV paoint event gets called and gets updated.

Comment: Noxthron. Its NewCustomersRow().But it doesnt work actually.Because it doesnt clear all the rows on click of new button.

Comment: jdweng. No advantage in setting datasource or datagridview or datatable to null because when i click on search and double click on added record it does not show me the data in the datagridview or datasource because it permanently clears that datasource at that point of time.